# Don't show media types which already exist in order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to display only those media types which are not present in the order. Please find below the code:

Error:

```
**NoMethodError in Orders#building
Showing /app/views/orders/_add_media_form.html.haml where line #51 raised:
undefined method `media_type_id' for
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
Extracted source (around line #51):

50      - if @request.media_type_id.empty? 
51        %table.media_search_results
```

**add_media_form.html.haml**

```
- if @request.media_type_id.empty? 
...    
        - @form.media_types.each do |media_type|
          %tr
            %td
              = text_field_tag "media_type_quantity[#{media_type.id}]", "",
                class: "quantity_input", type: :number, min: 0
            %td= media_type.name
```

**Orders Controller:**

```
def building

    @request = @order.media_order_requests
    @request.each.map{|request| media_types = MediaType.where.not(id: request.media_type_id)} #where media_type.id != requests.media_type_id
```

If I do this in add media form, it shows all media types in stock:

```
 - if @form.media_types.present? 
     %table
            - @form.media_types.each do |media_type|
              %tr
                %td
                  = text_field_tag "media_type_quantity[#{media_type.id}]", "",
                    class: "quantity_input"
                %td= media_type.name
                %td= media_type.measurement_suite.name
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error you are getting is because in your building method you set `@result` to `@order.media_order_requests` which is an `<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>`

```
    @request = @order.media_order_requests
```

An this is what `@result` will hold in your view.  So when you call `@request.media_type_id.empty?` in your view you are calling `media_type_id` on an `<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>` object,  which has no such method, and is the exact error message you get.

In your building method you have the following statement **after** the assignment of `@request`

```
@request.each.map{|request| media_types = MediaType.where.not(id: request.media_type_id)}
```

It seems like you are thinking this statement will modify `@request` but it does not, it simply returns a new array mapped according the block you give it.  That array is then returned by the `building` method and is probably never used.

In order to modify `@request` you would need to do something like `@request = @request.map ...` but you would probably be better off setting some new variable, which is where I think you were trying to go with the `media_types = MediaType.where.not(id: request.media_type_id)` statement in your map function.

There are more efficient ways to do this but,  since we don't see the details of our models,  you can try something like this

```
request_media_types = @order.media_order_requests.map { |r| r.media_type_id }  #hopefully this is a list of media_type_id's 
@media_types = MediaType.select { |mt| !request_media_types.include? mt.id } #select thos MediaType object whose id is not in the request_media_types list
```

I obviously can't test this but hopefully this gets you going in the right direction.

and then use `@media_types.empty?` in your view

As a side note,  it looks like you are doing a lot of logic in your views, logic belongs in models and controllers.

Comment: Thanks for much, very much appreciated. I will give it a go. Since I was working on existing code written by someone else, it was quite difficult. So now starting from scratch but keeping the same old models. I am new to programming for a profession : )